# extract a html ID from inside a tag using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract only an iid code in html so that i can append it to a url and open the page I need.

I can find the tag I need by specifying the class of the tag. However I also get 4 other tags in the output. All i want is the iid inside the first tag "183988596953"

I have tried using this code to specify only the idd

```
rslt_table = soup.find_all("iid",{"div class": "lvpic pic img left"})
```

This however only seems to return an empty list []

The output i get when repacing the line of code above with 2nd last line of code below is the output with 4 tags I mentioned

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

urls = ['https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=goldfinger+quad']

#https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=

def find_id(urls):
    for url in urls:
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.get(url)
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        rslt_table = soup.find("div", {"class": "lvpic pic img left"})
        return(rslt_table)
```

My search url is https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=goldfinger+quad'

Full outpt is

```
<div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="183988596953">
<div class="lvpicinner full-width picW">
<a class="img imgWr2" href="https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/GOLDFINGER-1964-Style-A-B-UK-Cinema-High-Quality-Repro-30-x-40-quad-poster/183988596953?hash=item2ad69330d9:g:rYQAAOSwrENdbmEW">
<img alt='GOLDFINGER 1964 Style A &amp; B -  UK Cinema High Quality Repro 30"x 40" quad poster' class="img" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/rYQAAOSwrENdbmEW/s-l225.jpg"/>
</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: use find to get first match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code updated:

- Use `attrs` to return all the attributes

  - `{'class': ['lvpic', 'pic', 'img', 'left'], 'iid': '183988596953'}`

```py
def find_id(urls):
    for url in urls:
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        return soup.find("div", {"class": "lvpic pic img left"}).attrs['iid']

iid = find_id(urls)

print(iid)

>>> '183988596953'
```

### If you want all `iid`:

```py
def find_id(urls):
    for url in urls:
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        div = s.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'lvpic pic img left'})
        return [iid.attrs['iid'] for iid in div]
```